# How to open txt file and write data into it in Eclipse C?

Tags: c, eclipse

I am trying to write data into existing file on my HDD in projects directory in Eclipse IDE, C language. So far I tried function fopen but since Eclipse uses small C library it wont work even with proper libraries included.
So is there a way to save data in text file?

```
char n[] = "6E436C703186B19CBC6BFD77DFD8FF3D85F7274793A0A";

char subn[40];
strncpy ( subn, n, 5);
subn[5] = '\0';

USART_TX_String(subn);

FILE *fp;
char* filename = "hexnumbers.txt";
fp = fopen( filename, "w" );
if( fp == NULL )
{
fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open file '%s'\n", filename );
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It would help to see your code,

Comment: Here it is @JohnBode I belive this part should be enought